# Definition of "the bedding"

Tags: idioms

After a wedding ceremony, "the bedding" took place.  Would that mean the bride and groom had conjugal relations?  I ran across this in Scottish court proceedings.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Questions here are expected to demonstrate some initial research effort; a web search turns up a Wikipedia article on *[bedding ceremony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bedding_ceremony)*,  which is probably not a bad place to start. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 3):

To ***bed*** someone means to have sex with someone.  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[bed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bed)***
>
> VERB
>
> 1. (bed down) *[no object]* Settle down to sleep or rest for the night in an improvised place.
>      *‘you can bed down in the shed’*
>
>    1.1 (bed someone/something down) *[with object]* Settle a person or animal down to sleep or rest for the night.
>      *‘she is grooming the horses and bedding them down for the night’*
>
>    1.2 *informal [with object]* Have sexual intercourse with.
>            *‘I am quite picky when it comes to bedding someone’*

Note especially #1.2

So, in the context of a wedding night, yes, it refers to the conjugal relations.

With many thanks to Spagirl, it appears that *the bedding* may very well be ritualistic and could be symbolic in nature.  Per the [Women's History Network](https://womenshistorynetwork.org/womens-history-month-bedding-rituals-in-scotland/):

> In Scotland amongst the lower-classes, it was not uncommon for couples to be put to bed by their family and friends at the end of the wedding, a symbolic behaviour showing the communities endorsement of the marriage and the following consummation. Like elsewhere, it was not uncommon for the wedding party to continue to celebrate in the couple’s absence, and at some weddings, the bedding is purely symbolic. The couple are only left together alone for a few minutes, before they rejoin the party.

Comment: With an element of ritual context https://womenshistorynetwork.org/womens-history-month-bedding-rituals-in-scotland/

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not just sex for the sake of it. The bedding is the official consummation of the marriage. An unconsummated marriage was unsecured and the bedding assured both families that the marriage bonds were tightly bound.